# D3.js - force directed graph not interactive

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build a simple interactive force directed graph using d3.js v5. [I'm using this code as a template](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph/2?intent=fork), and I'm running the code using VSCode's live server.

The main body of my HTML code looks like this

```
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/graph.js"></script>
```

and the script itself looks like this

```
const nodes = [
    { id: 1 }, 
    { id: 2 }, 
    { id: 3 }
];

const links = [
    { source: 1, target: 2 },
    { source: 2, target: 3 },
    { source: 3, target: 1 }
];

// Specify the dimensions of the chart.
const width = 928;
const height = 600;

// Specify the color scale.
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

// Create a simulation with several forces.
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .on("tick", ticked);

// Create the SVG container.
const svg = d3.create("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;");

// Add a line for each link, and a circle for each node.
const link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#999")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
    .selectAll()
    .data(links)
    .join("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.sqrt(d.value));

const node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .selectAll()
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.group));

node.append("title")
    .text(d => d.id);

// Add a drag behavior.
node.call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

// Set the position attributes of links and nodes each time the simulation ticks.
function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
}

// Reheat the simulation when drag starts, and fix the subject position.
function dragstarted(event) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
    event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
}

// Update the subject (dragged node) position during drag.
function dragged(event) {
    event.subject.fx = event.x;
    event.subject.fy = event.y;
}

// Restore the target alpha so the simulation cools after dragging ends.
// Unfix the subject position now that it’s no longer being dragged.
function dragended(event) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    event.subject.fx = null;
    event.subject.fy = null;
}
document.body.appendChild(svg.node());
```

but all I'm getting is this
[image: sad triangle]
and I can't interact with it or anything. What am I missing?

Comment: Your code sample is `d3` version 7.  You are running it with `d3` version 5.  See your code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/4fuL5joCpTBASdbw) with v7.